# How to implement an SVG image support in Svelte Native App

Tags: user-interface, svg, nativescript, native, svelte

For the moment I work with the Svelte framework and have reached the point to create an app by the use of Svelte Native which is a mix of Svelte and Nativescript. Both of them does not support SVG images to be used directly, however it is possible to use plugins/packages for different frameworks like Vue and React, or for plain Nativescript itself. There is no any official SVG support for Svelte Native, but I suppose, it can be done.

To implement SVG images I have already tried many Svelte packages like svelte-inline-svg, svelte-svg etc. I have also tried to register in app.ts and use nativescript plugins such as nativescript-svg, ui-svg and so on, but still no response. The only really working solution found from other repositories is to transfer SVG to PNG on the building stage. I hope I will find a smart coder who has already managed this and will share the experiance.

Comment: The Svelte discord also has a #nativedev channel https://discord.com/channels/457912077277855764/545629212921430026 In case you haven't already, you might also want to ask there

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use discord, so could you please share and make a reference on the topic if possible?